# How to merge two rows into a single one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df, looking like this and I would like to change it.

| time | lenght | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hh:mm:ss | cm | kg |
| 12:05:26 | 150 | 80 |

into this :

| time (hh:mm:ss) | lenght (cm) | Weight (kg) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12:05:26 | 150 | 80 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should most certainly try to fix this issue during import of your data.** Using for example `header=[0, 1]` in `read_csv`.

That said, you could use:

```
df2 = df.iloc[1:].set_axis([f'{a} ({b})' for a,b in zip(df.columns, df.iloc[0])], axis=1)
```

output:

```
  time (hh:mm:ss) lenght (cm) Weight (kg)
1        12:05:26         150          80
```

*Note that that dtypes will probably be incorrect, which is why fixing the import is highly recommended.*